# Getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable for Editor in selenium in Java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium3

I have a Text Editor where I want to perform `Sendkeys()` but getting 'element not interactable' error. I'm able to get the text of that element by `getText()`. No idea how to work with this editor. please help.

[image: Here is the screenshot of element]

Below is my code

```
WebElement frames = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
        driver.switchTo().frame(frames);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//section[@role='region']//p")));
        WebElement sections = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//section[@role='region']//p"));
        System.out.println(sections.getText());
        sections.sendKeys("some text");
```

Comment: Provide the code u used , and the website if possible

Comment: I tried only for Section tag but did not worked

Comment: This is the code i used driver.switchTo().frame(CKiframe.get(0));
  System.out.println(SectionsFields.get(0).getText());  
  SectionsFields.get(0).sendKeys(TitleDescription);

Comment: show the locator please, page object code won't do any help in debugging. Also try sending to p tag if section is not working

Comment: If i try to click on that element to bring it to focus it giving 'stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document'.

Comment: may be you shoul use explicitwait for the page to load fully before doing something

Comment: My code is updated in question.